# Laravel - recreate cookie login

Tags: authentication, cookies, encryption, laravel-4

I am creating an application which hits an external service (db) to see if a user is authenticated.
so:

```
User submits username and password -> hit service -> returns false or user row from db
```

Where i am stuck is i now need to login the user into my laravel app. I am thinking what i need to do is something like:

```
Auth::login($user);
```

And mimic Laravels User Object

or recreate laravel's encrypted cookie, so the application thinks the user is logged in.

I do not have/want access to the db that the external service uses. That is not an option
Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Anyone use micro service and only template in Laravel. Should I just completely bypass Laravel authentication and create my own encrypted cookie?

Answer (score 1):

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually

> If you need to log an existing user instance into your application,
>   you may simply call the login method with the instance:
>
> ```
> $user = User::find(1);
> Auth::login($user);
> ```
>
> This is equivalent to logging in a user via credentials using the
>   attempt method.

Comment: I understand that, except the db and the laravel application do not talk. We need to communicate with an external service which will then tell us if the user is authenticated. We then need to login the user to our Laravel App. So i am seeing the two options as recreate laravel encrypted cookie or copy the user model/class. I am not sure what the best way to do this is.